# Safari browser not decoding the filename set in content-disposition header

Tags: safari, urlencode, content-disposition

I had encoded the filename using org.apache.catalina.util.URLEncoder and set in content-disposition header as follows:

```
String encoded = urlEncoder.encode(fileName, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\""+encodedFileName+"\"");
```

Filename : **ຕົວຢ່າງ.pptx**

Encoded : **%E0%BA%95%E0%BA%BB%E0%BA%A7%E0%BA%A2%E0%BB%88%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%87%pptx**

While downloading in Chrome browser it decodes and download correctly. But Safari does not decode the name, it downloads in the encoded format.

Also, the extension is appended to the filename while downloading from Safari browser.
Like **%E0%BA%95%E0%BA%BB%E0%BA%A7%E0%BA%A2%E0%BB%88%E0%BA%B2%E0%BA%87%2Epptx.pptx**

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I tried adding UTF-8 and it worked.

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename*=UTF-8''\""+encodedFileName+"\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because URL-encoding the filename is not portable.

All the details are in RFC 6266; the format described over there will work with all current browsers.